# How to set inner margins in ion-card? Ionic 4

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build a card with just text and I want the text to be at certain distance to the border.

- In the first case I set a padding for the card but the top and bottom
  space is too big.
- In the second case I dont use padding, but it is removed also from
  right and left.
- In the third case I am just using a dirty trick moving the start of
  the text 16px from the left my this **CSS**:

  ```
  .lefts {    
    position: relative; 
    left: 16px; 
  }
  ```

  But still Im not fixing the right margin, and moreover I dont think this is a proper solution

[image]

**What I want?** 
To have a card with the top and bottom margins like in the second (Desde Sevilla) but with the right and left like the first one (Desde Malaga)

See **.html**

```
<ion-card padding>    
<ion-text class="bold" color="primary"><p>DESDE MALAGA</p></ion-text>
<ion-text color="dark"><p>Son 4 horas en <a href='http://www.tgcomes.es/horarios_3.htm'>Autobus</a> o 2.5 en coche (ruta muy comun en <a href='https://m.blablacar.es/ride-sharing/malaga/cadiz/'>Blablacar</a>)</p></ion-text>    
</ion-card>

<ion-card>    
  <ion-text class="bold" color="primary"><p>DESDE SEVILLA</p></ion-text>
  <ion-text color="dark"><p>Se tarda 1h45 en <a href='http://www.tgcomes.es/horarios_13.htm'>Autobus</a> o 1h40 en <a href='http://www.renfe.com/'>Tren hasi aiuu ei aiwh</a></p></ion-text>    
</ion-card>


<ion-card>    
  <ion-text class="bold.left" color="primary"><p>DESDE JEREZ</p></ion-text>
  <ion-text class="lefts" color="dark"><p>Es el aeropuerto mas pequeño, si viajas desde fuera de España tendrás que hacer escala en Madrid o Barcelona. Desde Jerez son 30 minutos en coche o 1 hora en <a href='http://www.aena.mobi/m/en/jerez-airport/train.html'>Transporte Publico.</a>
  Es posible que nosotros o alguien de nuestra familia os recoja.</p></ion-text>    
</ion-card>
```

I am also using this **CSS** but I dont think is relevant, just in case:

```
ion-card {
    border-top: 3px solid #d15b5b;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d15b5b;
    border-left: 3px solid #d15b5b;
    border-right: 3px solid #d15b5b    
}
```

Comment: You can use a custom style to specify padding for all the sides. For example: `padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px`. You can specify padding based on your needs.

Comment: Add padding to yourr `ion-card` tag. `padding: 0px 15px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ion-card {border: 3px solid #d15b5b;padding: 10px 15px;}

Answer (score -2):

Ideally, you would use the `ion-card` component as intended, with all (or part of) its child components:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-subtitle>Card Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
    <ion-card-title>Card Title</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
    and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Padding here is provided by `<ion-card-content>` and could be adapted via local, overriding CSS.

EDIT:
Adding link to [Ionic's API doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/card)

Comment: I know the behaviour of ion-card. However this is not answering my quesiton

Comment: **i am getting down-voted bc of pointing out the correct usage?** interesting!
especially since you **didn't point** that you deliberately used the ion-card component against documentation.